# How to make a particular peer 'endorsing peer' in hyperledger fabric v1.0

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Having read [the official doc](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/endorsement-policies.html), I know that endorsement policy is defined at chaincode instantiation using the '-P' flag.

The doc suggests something like this: `-P "AND('Org1.member','Org2.member')"` However, the 'member' field is not visible in the network-config.json.

Can anyone explain...

1. What is a 'member' representing in the 'Org1.member'
2. Can we directly mention peers like this: "AND('Org1.peer2',         'Org2.peer1')"`
3. Can we address peers with ip like this: "AND('localhost:7051',         'localhost:7052')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is a 'member' representing in the 'Org1.member'?

The `member` key word is a principal which identifies the role within the organization, so for example a `member` stays for regular entity, while for example `admin`, will mean that to endorse transaction one with admin rights has to sign it.

> 2. Can we directly mention peers like this: "AND('Org1.peer2', 'Org2.peer1')"`

No you cannot mention peer directly in the endorsement policies.

> 3. Can we address peers with ip like this: "AND('localhost:7051', 'localhost:7052')"`

And you cannot use endpoints neither.

In order to turn any peer to an endorsing peer for some chaincode, you have to install the chaincode on that peer, doing that will allow you to forward endorsement request to that peer. Of course assuming its part of the channel and chaincode is being instantiated in that channel.

Comment: When I propose a transaction to endorsers, can I specify "member" or "admin" for endorsement ?

Comment: @TanakaHiroyuki you have to specify it while instantiating a chaincode using -P flag

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I mean, when client application proposes a transaction to endorser,  how the client application can chooses to obtain member endorsement or admin endorsement ?

Answer (score 1):

in HLF v1.1 identity classification is enabled thus it is now possible to specify "peers" in the endorsement policy. from the official docs:
`A principal is described in terms of the MSP that is tasked to validate the identity of the signer and of the role that the signer has within that MSP. Four roles are supported: member, admin, client, and peer. Principals are described as MSP.ROLE, where MSP is the MSP ID that is required, and ROLE is one of the four strings member, admin, client and peer. Examples of valid principals are 'Org0.admin' (any administrator of the Org0 MSP) or 'Org1.member' (any member of the Org1 MSP), 'Org1.client' (any client of the Org1 MSP), and 'Org1.peer' (any peer of the Org1 MSP).`
though it does not allow to specify named peers or endpoints